# GEOjson not displaying in my map openlayers

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, openlayers, geojson

I want to display geojson data in my map openLayers but my data didn't show and the map doesn't even display. I work with openLayers 5.
I have an api (in node.js) which allows to extract the data in my database. 
I have a file (script.js) which allows to display the map, recover the data sent by the api and display the data on the map.

In script.js :

I create a new vectorLayer which contain the style of the geojson :

```
 var foncier2 = new VectorLayer({
source:source,
style: function (feature, res) {
  property = feature.get("nature");
  return new  Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: [40, 40, 40, 1],
      width: 0.3
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: couleur(property)
    })
  })
},});
```

I request on my API to recover the data with the help of a callback :

```
`
function loadJSON(callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            callback(this.responseText);
          }
        };
        xhr.open("GET", "adressIP:port/endpoint", true);
        // xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send(null);
      }`
```

Then I create a function which transform the data into json then into GEOjson :

```
   var myData = JSON.parse(data);

var geojsonObject = {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:4326" }},
 "features": [
   {
     "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
       "type": "Polygon",
       "coordinates":myData[2].geom
     }
   }
 ]};
```

Finally i display the data :

```
foncier2.getSource().clear();
foncier2.getSource().addFeatures(foncier2.getSource().getFormat().readFeatures(geojsonObject, {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  defaultFeatureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
}));
foncier2.getSource().refresh();
foncier2.getSource().changed();
map.getView().fit(foncier2.getSource().getExtent());
```

But
nothing displays on my map and I don't have error in my console log.

Thank you for helping me

PS : ( I managed to recover the data,it looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blJST.png) and [the coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8frt1.png) )

Comment: The option in `readFeatures` should be `featureProjection` (not `defaultFeatureProjection`).  If that doesn't fix it could you include your code where you create `source` to check the format is specified correctly?

Comment: I change the readFeatures to featureProjection but the issue still the same.  
 The code  for the source :                                                                                 
 var source = new VectorSource({
    format: new GeoJSON(),

    features: [],
 
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting coordinates to the geometry (which your screenshot shows is multipolygon) instead of the geometry's coordinates and not updating the type.  Try this:

```
var geojsonObject = {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:4326" }},
 "features": [
   {
     "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
       "type": JSON.parse(myData[2].geom).type,
       "coordinates": JSON.parse(myData[2].geom).coordinates
     }
   }
 ]};
```

Comment: Thanks you for you advice my problem is almost solve , now my map is showing. But the GEOjson don't appears because my console shows : " Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined ". So i have done a console.log(myData[2].geom.type) it's show me "undefined". I didn't use the proper way to display the data ?

Comment: I've just noticed an extra `"` in your screenshot so although you parsed `data` the `geom` value in the data is still a string, so that will also need parsing.